# When two dives with the same class select first div

Tags: css, sass

would be glad if someone would help :)

Depending on the situation, there are two possibilities. Two divs with the same class side by side, and div with different classes, depending on the situation I would like to add css to the first div with class image when next to is albo div with class image

1.

```
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
```

2. .image {
   padding-right: 40px;
   }

Is it possible two give some rule like below but only for the first div with class image when the second div with class image is next to.

```
.image + .image {
   padding-right: 5px
}
```

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please pick the best answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select depending on descendants or subsequent siblings; from any point you've already reached in your selector, you can only select onward/downward.

What you can do to achieve the desired result is to put a wrapper element around your elements, and then exclude `:last-child`:

```css
.outer { font-size: 0; border: 1px solid #333; display: inline-block; }

.inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.inner:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```